# Dynamically Updating Form Action Failing Intermittently

Tags: javascript, jquery

Upon clicking a link, I'm triggering a modal and dynamically setting the form action contained in the modal based on the link clicked.

It works nearly every time; however, the tester is reporting that maybe 1 in 50 times, the action is not updated. The intermittent failure has been reproduced in IE11 and latest Chrome.

Below is the gist of the code

```
<ul>
  <li><a class="action_url" href="http://somedomain.com">Some Domain</a></li>
  <li><a class="action_url" href="http://anotherdomain.com">Another Domain</a></li>
  <li><a class="action_url" href="http://yetanotherdomain.com">Yet Another Domain</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Post Your Message</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form role="form" class="message-form" method="post" action="">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="message" name="message" value="">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Post</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).on("click", ".action_url", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".message-form").attr('action', e.target.href);
  $("#myModal").modal();
});
</script>
```

And a link to
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sjordan/s2ymppqr/)

I've created an alternate version that uses setTimeout (but that's a bit of a hack and more importantly didn't completely eliminate the issue)

Anyone seen this issue in the wild? Know the cause? And most important, the fix?

Comment: Try this, https://jsfiddle.net/t8hogmzo/ , hope it works for you

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Thank you. Upon initial testing, it seems to work. I'll give it to the tester who will bang on it. Very interested if you can explain why your design with the use of a callback would work more consistently.

Comment: The reason is that the callback only runs after the code inside the function is done. aka it should not open the modal before the `attr` has been loaded

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Tester is still reporting some failures. Hmmmm...

Comment: I've updated this, https://jsfiddle.net/1rhdLcb7/ but its a long shot,if it dont work then you have to be more specific about when and where it fails

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Thank you. I will pass it to the tester. Much appreciate your help.